# How to implement external fingerprint device SDK in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am making a app which registers fingerprint of the employees for registration. However I am facing difficulty in implementing the external fingerprint device SDK in my app. I have imported it as module but the gradle keeps on giving me error on syncing and the sync fails with error message as:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
```

Here is my gradle code:

For app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.employeeRegistration"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

repositories {
google()
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation project(':readerUSBISO')
}
```

For project:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

For Fingerprint sdk:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.fpdemo"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
}

buildTypes {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation files('libs/fgtitdevice.jar')
}
```

Help me with this situation.

Comment: What's your "readerUSBISO" ?

Comment: "readerUSBISO" is the android project file for using the functionality of the device.